# Event trigger when cross-domain content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, cross-domain

I'm using the Facebook comments social plugin, however it's causing an issue with the height of content loaded. I'd like to set-up a custom scrollbar to contain the height of the loaded comments, but keep the style in line with the rest of the website.

The problem is the plugin I'm using to render a custom scrollbar needs to be re-called everytime the content inside changes. Given that the content is pulled cross-domain, I'm wondering if there's a way to check when it loads/changes and if so what it is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've looked through the documentation on the [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) but can't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [jquery $.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), when you received the `data`, you can do other stuff.